Need help for the python scheduling code
I'm working on a Python application using PuLP for optimization, and I'm having trouble ensuring that only one material is produced on a given day.
The constraint prob += pulp.lpSum(production_flag[m][d] for m in materials) <= 1 is intended to ensure that only one material is produced on a given day. However, it doesn't seem to be working as expected. Multiple materials are still being scheduled for production on the same day. How can I modify my constraints or logic to ensure that only one material is produced on any given day?
Below is my current code:
materials = ["600065", "600047", "600063", "600076", "600061"]
current_date = datetime(2024, 6, 13)
current_inventory = {
    "600065": {current_date: 247.5},
    "600047": {current_date: 0},
    "600063": {current_date: 205.2},
    "600076": {current_date: 80},
    "600061": {current_date: 1.2}
}

quantity_to_be_sold = {
    "600065": {datetime(2024, 6, 14): 25,
               datetime(2024, 6, 15): 55,
               datetime(2024, 6, 18): 25, 
               datetime(2024, 6, 20): 25, 
               datetime(2024, 6, 21): 25, 
               datetime(2024, 6, 27): 25, 
               datetime(2024, 6, 28): 25, 
               datetime(2024, 6, 30): 50},
    "600047": {datetime(2024, 6, 24): 25},
    "600063": {datetime(2024, 6, 14): 52.8, 
               datetime(2024, 6, 15): 79.2,
               datetime(2024, 6, 21): 26.4, 
               datetime(2024, 6, 22): 79.2, 
               datetime(2024, 6, 28): 52.8},
    "600076": {datetime(2024, 6, 14): 20, 
               datetime(2024, 6, 15): 20,
               datetime(2024, 6, 18): 40, 
               datetime(2024, 6, 19): 40, 
               datetime(2024, 6, 24): 20,
               datetime(2024, 6, 26): 20,
               datetime(2024, 6, 27): 20,
               datetime(2024, 6, 28): 20,
               datetime(2024, 6, 21): 20},
    "600061": {datetime(2024, 6, 21): 26.4}
}

production_capacity = {"600065": 80,"600047": 80, "600063": 36, "600076": 30, "600061": 36}
waiting_period = {"600065": 1,"600047": 1, "600063": 2, "600076": 2, "600061": 2}

#Collect all dates from input data and current inventory
all_dates = sorted(set(date for dates in quantity_to_be_sold.values() for date in dates).union(
    date for dates in current_inventory.values() for date in dates))

#Define the problem
prob = pulp.LpProblem("AS_Packaging_Optimization", pulp.LpMaximize)

#Define decision variables
production = pulp.LpVariable.dicts("Production", (materials, all_dates), 0, None, pulp.LpContinuous)
inventory = pulp.LpVariable.dicts("Sales", (materials, all_dates), 0, None, pulp.LpContinuous)
available_for_sale = pulp.LpVariable.dicts("AvailableForSale", (materials, all_dates), 0, None, pulp.LpContinuous)
production_flag = pulp.LpVariable.dicts("ProductionFlag", (materials, all_dates), 0, 1, pulp.LpBinary)

#Objective function: Maximize total sales
prob += pulp.lpSum([quantity_to_be_sold[m].get(d, 0) for m in materials for d in all_dates])

def get_cumulative_production(production_data, current_date, waiting_period, all_dates):
    cumulative_production = 0
    start_date = current_date - timedelta(days=waiting_period-1)
    
    for date in all_dates:
        if start_date <= date <= current_date and date in production_data:
           cumulative_production += production_data[date]
    
    return cumulative_production

#Constraints: Inventory
for m in materials:
    for i, d in enumerate(all_dates):
        # Inventory balance constraints
        if i == 0:
            prob += inventory[m][d] == current_inventory[m].get(d, 0)
        else:
            prev_day = all_dates[i - 1]
            prob += inventory[m][d] == inventory[m][prev_day] + production[m][d] - quantity_to_be_sold[m].get(d, 0)

        # Available for sale considering the waiting period
        if i == 0:
            prob += available_for_sale[m][d] == inventory[m][d]
        else:
            production_data = {date: production[m][date] for date in all_dates}
            total_production_deduction = get_cumulative_production(production_data, d, waiting_period[m], all_dates)
            prob += available_for_sale[m][d] == inventory[m][d] - total_production_deduction
    
#Constraint: Materials and Production on initial day 
for m in materials:
    for d in current_inventory[m]:
        prob += production[m][d] == 0

#Constraint: Materials and Production on subsequent day 
for d in all_dates:
    prob += pulp.lpSum(production_flag[m][d] for m in materials) <= 1
    for m in materials:  
        prob += production[m][d] <= production_capacity[m] * production_flag[m][d]
        prob += production[m][d] >= 0 
    
#Solve the problem
prob.solve()

# Extract results
def extract_results(material):
    results = {
        "Date": [],
        "Material": [],
        "Production": [],
        "Sales": [],
        "Inventory": [],
        "AvailableForSale": []
    }

    for d in all_dates:
        results["Date"].append(d.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))
        results["Material"].append(material)
        results["Production"].append(pulp.value(production[material][d]))
        results["Sales"].append(quantity_to_be_sold[material].get(d, 0))
        results["Inventory"].append(pulp.value(inventory[material][d]))
        results["AvailableForSale"].append(pulp.value(available_for_sale[material][d]))

    df_results = pd.DataFrame(results)
    return df_results

# Extract results for each material
df_results_600065 = extract_results("600065")
df_results_600047 = extract_results("600047")
df_results_600063 = extract_results("600063")
df_results_600076 = extract_results("600076")
df_results_600061 = extract_results("600061")

print("Results for Material 600065:")
print(df_results_600065 if isinstance(df_results_600065, pd.DataFrame) else df_results_600065)
print("Results for Material 600047:")
print(df_results_600047 if isinstance(df_results_600047, pd.DataFrame) else df_results_600047)
print("\nResults for Material 600063:")
print(df_results_600063 if isinstance(df_results_600063, pd.DataFrame) else df_results_600063)
print("\nResults for Material 600076:")
print(df_results_600076 if isinstance(df_results_600076, pd.DataFrame) else df_results_600076)
print("\nResults for Material 600061:")
print(df_results_600061 if isinstance(df_results_600061, pd.DataFrame) else df_results_600061)


When I run your code on my machine, Pulp says that the problem is infeasible. You should first figure out why this is the case.

Hi, PeterD thank you for your comment. I run it on Jupyter Notebook and the results is feasible (I am not sure it's infeasible, but the result can expose??). Sorry, i am newbie for this thing.

It might show you values for your variables, but this does not mean its feasible. In my case Pulp says that is proved to be infeasible.

Could you tell me where do you run this code?

I add the extract data part after prob.solve.
Could you run it to see the result?  Thank you very much -/-

On a Windows machine, using the CBC MILP solver version 2.10.3. Yes I can see the results, including the variables, but its still infeasible. What does print(pulp.LpStatus[-1]) return?

It returns Infeasible. That means i have to revise some constraint right due to it might conflict from each other, right? Thank you again.

Thank you so much, I review my code again, and i found I made mistaken on the initial input parameters T.T. I do this step for a week, i think the solution is feasible all the time and revise the constraint again and again.
My solution is solved right now!

That can be the case, but it can also be due to your parameters (e.g., your production capacities).

I review my code again, and i found I made mistaken on the initial input parameters T.T. I do this step for a week, i think the solution is feasible all the time and revise the constraint again and again. My solution is solved right now!
